# I cant mount or see files of my sda5 after reinstalling grub

Tags: partitioning, grubrescue

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 I recently had this error of my system dropping to busy box then later on it dropped to grub and could not load further

I later found the video on YouTube of reinstalling grub using the something else. I did not want to loose my file so I did not format the drive. The problem now is that I cant access my files but properties still show that the space that was initially covered by my stuff has the files. I cant access or see those files. Please help I am new to Linux.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you have done, but lets assume you can boot into you Ubuntu OS.  Is sda5 mounted ? In fact, let me write something as an answr so i can format it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that /dev/sda5 is not mounted already, so lets mount it manually.

Make a directory called mydisk somewhere convenient, lets say in your home directory.

```
cd /home/<username>
mkdir mydisk
```

Mount sda5 to the new mydisk directory

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /home/<username>/mydisk
```

Now change into that directory.

```
cd /home/<username>/mydisk
```

Take a look at whats inside.

```
ls -la
```

Do you see all your files and folders ?